# why the data has changed after convert to parquet format testing by union two dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parquet

I wrote a function to operation on a csv file, to convert it to parquet format.
and I wonder how to make sure the data is the same,not lost or add.
So I wrote a test for it. But it turns out they are not the same:
My logic is:

1) make the csv to dataframe **A**.

2)and make the dataframe **A** to parquet format ,save to a dir.

3)read the parquet file to be a new dataframe **B**.

4)then  **A.union(B)**.

5)count the A and B and A.union(B).

If the three are the same ,then I can get to the conclusion that they are the same data.
But I get third one different.

```
def doJob(sc: SparkContext, data: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {
    logInfo("Extracting omniture data")
    val result = data
      .filter(_.contains("PAGE."))
      .filter(_.contains(".PACKAGE"))
    val sqlsqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

//just ignore above codes...

    val packagesCsvDF = sqlsqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "file:///D:/test/testsample.csv", "header" -> "true"))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

//
//    // we should have some additional filter here
//    val mydf = packagesDF.groupBy($"page_url").agg(last($"pagename"),last($"prop46"),last($"prop56"),last($"post_evar34"))
//    logInfo("show mydf")
//    mydf.show()

    //TODO
    // save files
    logInfo("Saving omniture packages data to S3")
    if (true) {
      packagesCsvDF
        .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, col("pagename"))
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .partitionBy("pagename")
        .parquet("file:///D:/test/parquet")
      logInfo("packagesDF")

    }

    packagesCsvDF//Is this packagesCsvDF have not been changed yet??????
  }
```

TEST:

```
object ParquetDataTestsSpec {
  def main (args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("parquet data test Logs").setMaster("local"))


    val input = PackagesOmnitureMapReduceJob.formatToJson(sc.textFile("file:///D:/test/option.json", sc.defaultParallelism))
    val df = PackagesOmnitureMapReduceJob.doJob(sc, input)//call the function I want to test in "file:///D:/test/parquet"
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val SourceCSVDF = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "file:///D:/test/testsample.csv", "header" -> "true"))// original 

    val parquetDataFrame = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///D:/test/parquet") //get the new dataframe

    val dfCount = df.count()
    val SourceCSVDFcount = SourceCSVDF.count()
    val parquetDataCount = parquetDataFrame.count()

    val unionCount = parquetDataFrame.union(SourceCSVDF).count()
    println(dfCount,SourceCSVDFcount,parquetDataCount,unionCount)


  }
}
```

print:

```
(200,200,200,400)
```

then I try to parse all the dataframe to json:

```
parquetDataFrame.write.json("file:///D:/test/parquetDataFrame")
SourceCSVDF.write.json("file:///D:/test/SourceCSVDF")
df.write.json("file:///D:/test/Desktop/df")
```

and when I open the json files, I find they are so all same..Is the problem is coming with the key word **union**?

Answer (score 0):

```
val unionalldis3 = parquetDataFrame.unionAll(SourceCSVDF).distinct().count()
```

then it is right...

But I am very confused.I thought union() is the distincted unionAll....